# Sublime Text 3 SASS Build error, cannot build a css file

Tags: css, sass, sublimetext3

I'm using SASSBuild on Sublime Text3 to save style.scss as a nested .css but keep failing with exit code 64.

All installs were successful:
-packages: SASS, SCSS, SASSBuild
-SASS using brew
-Preinstalled Ruby from Mac

When I try to Tools->Build->SASS with style.scss saved on desktop/SCSS, it shows this message and nothing happens:

```
Could not find an option named "cache".

Usage: sass <input.scss> [output.css]
       sass <input.scss>:<output.css> <input/>:<output/>

━━━ Input and Output ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
    --[no-]stdin               Read the stylesheet from stdin.
    --[no-]indented            Use the indented syntax for input from stdin.
-I, --load-path=<PATH>         A path to use when resolving imports.
                               May be passed multiple times.

-s, --style=<NAME>             Output style.
                               [expanded (default), compressed]

    --update                   Only compile out-of-date stylesheets.

━━━ Source Maps ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
    --[no-]source-map          Whether to generate source maps.
                               (defaults to on)

    --source-map-urls          How to link from source maps to source files.
                               [relative (default), absolute]

    --[no-]embed-sources       Embed source file contents in source maps.
    --[no-]embed-source-map    Embed source map contents in CSS.

━━━ Other ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
    --watch                    Watch stylesheets and recompile when they change.
    --[no-]poll                Manually check for changes rather than using a native watcher.
                               Only valid with --watch.

    --[no-]stop-on-error       Don't compile more files once an error is encountered.
-i, --interactive              Run an interactive SassScript shell.
-c, --[no-]color               Whether to emit terminal colors.
-q, --[no-]quiet               Don't print warnings.
    --[no-]trace               Print full Dart stack traces for exceptions.
-h, --help                     Print this usage information.
    --version                  Print the version of Dart Sass.
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 64]
[cmd: ['sass', '--update', '/Users/adrian/Desktop/SCSS/style.scss:/Users/name/Desktop/SCSS/style.css', '--stop-on-error', '--no-cache']]
[dir: /Users/name/Desktop/SCSS]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

How can I get the SASSBuild to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you use `gulp` or `wepback` its pretty easier than sublime.

Answer (score 6):

This error happens when you have Dart SASS installed (which is the newer, preferred module) instead of Node SASS. The built-in script uses the `--no-cache` option, which isn't present in the Dart SASS module.

You can easily add your own build file to use instead of the built-in:

In Sublime, select

```
Tools > Build System > New Build System...
```

Which will open a new file inside your Sublime **User** folder. Use the following script:

```
{ 
    "cmd" : [
        "sass", 
        "--update", 
        ".:.", 
        "--stop-on-error", 
        "--style", 
        "compressed"
    ],
    "selector": "source.scss"
}
```

You can set any of the [Dart SASS options](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass) you wish, for example change *compressed* to *expanded*.

[More information on Sublime Build Systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/exec.html).

Then, just save this file (perhaps *Dart-SASS.sublime-build*) and then select it as your build system from the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new Build System, you could also fix the wrong params (e.g. `--no-cache`) brought to you by the "SASS Build" plugin.

1. Install [**PackageResourceViews**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) (lets you change any content in your packages)
2. Launch "**PackageResourceViewer: OpenResource**"
3. choose "**SASS Build**"
4. select "**SASS.sublime-build**" and/or "**SASS - Compressed.sublime-build**"
5. fix wrong arguments, save and close
6. try to build your sass!

btw, this is my build file; "--no-cache" removed from "cmd":

```
{
    "cmd": ["sass", "--update", "$file:${file_path}/${file_base_name}.css", "--stop-on-error"],
    "selector": "source.sass, source.scss",
    "line_regex": "Line ([0-9]+):",

    "osx":
    {
        "path": "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    },

    "windows":
    {
        "shell": "true"
    }

}
```